# How to refresh Dialog when the data has change? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dialog, refresh

I'm a new Flutter developer and I have a problem, which I haven't been able to solve yet, even if I tried a lot.

I'm developing an App, where at some point a Dialog is opened(with showDialog()). In this Dialog there are 2 AutoCompleteTextField:

- In the first one, the data will always be the same. So there is a list and the user needs to choose one of the choices. [First AutoCompleteTextField code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8X7T.png)
- In the second one, the data to be shown depends on the previous choice. In other words,
  whenever an item from the previous list is chosen, the subdata of the item will be requested. [Second AutoCompleteTextField code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3km7M.png)

The required data is fetched properly, however the dialog is not refreshing state so the suggestions of the second AutoCompleteTextField appears empty. When I close and enter again the suggestions of the second appears as they should.

To get notified when the data changes I use ChangeNotifier and Provider, but doesn´t refresh the Dialog ([ChangeNotifier class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Tgy.png)). I also use StatefulBuilder to be able to use setState, but again, doesn´t refresh ([Dialog code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rETFD.png)).

I would like to know if there is any other way to refresh the Dialog. Thank you!

PD: This is my first question in StackOverflow. I tried my best.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Provider.of(context) to be able to listen to the updates and refresh or add/update the data.

[Provider.of(context)](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Provider/of.html)

I would create a widget class instead of the _widgetTask function and then use Provider.of(context) inside the widget build function like following (I think you can also try to add it inside the _widgetTask function but I dont know if this would work).

```
class WidgetTask extends StatelessWidget {
  //WidgetTask contructor here..
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final odooData = Provider.of<OdooData>(context);
```

And then use the odooData to access the data/functions you need to update/listen to from the provider.

Also you can wrap the widget with GestureDetector so that you can update the widget upon tapping using the OnTap property.

[flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter)[dart](/questions/tagged/dart)[dialog](/questions/tagged/dialog)[refresh](/questions/tagged/refresh)[provider](/questions/tagged/provider)[consumer](/questions/tagged/consumer)

Comment: Thank you very much for anwering my question. I tried by doing it as you said, but it happens the same. The main state rebuilds, however the dialog doesn´t. Right now, I´m trying to use ListenableProvider. I will update if I solve the problem.